# Including a Decimal For All Values

Tags: sas

Hi I need to change my code so that in my results it doesn't show numbers like 172.02 as 172. The numbers in my dataset that don't have .0 look something like 174.5. I want all of the numbers to have a decimal point and one more digit after that My data is in a column called pre_weight1. I've tried the code below.

```
   Length pre_weight1 $ 5.1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code solved my problem.

```
   format pre_weight1 5.2;
```

Answer (score 0):

The LENGTH in SAS is used to define how many bytes should be used to store the variable (and whether it is numeric or character).  So a LENGTH is always an integer value.   Note that SAS stores all numbers as 64-bit floating point numbers so use a length of 8 for numeric variables to avoid loss of precision.

If you want to change how a variable's value is displayed then change the FORMAT that is used with the variable.  You can use a FORMAT statement to do that.  You can use it either in the procedure where you are displaying the variable, or if used in the step that creates the dataset then it will be stored in the metadata of the dataset and be attached to the variable to be used as the default display method.

In a format specification the number before the period is the total width and the number after the period is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point. So if you want to display values from -99.9 to 999.9 you could use a format of `5.1`.

```
length pre_weight1 8 ;
format pre_weight 5.1;
```